# Jar Applet in HTML

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I've seen topics like this alraedy, but its not working for me.

So I have a game that succesfully made into an applet and it has many classes that are in a package called Build9.  I want to put it on my website.

My file structure is the html file in the root "Desktop/My Name" and I have a media folder that has the RomanFury.jar.

I've tried every combination of changing around the code and archive in the HTML tag.  With the classic:

```
<applet code="Main" archive="RomanFury.jar" width="1280" height="720">
My game.
</applet>
```

I get an error that says it cannot find Main.  If I put media/RomanFury.jar or put media/ infront of main the same kind of error is given.

Can someone tell me the correct html tag?

My .class files are in a folder called "Build9" in RomanFury.jar.

Comment: Please share some more information and code

Comment: There really isn't that much to share, what I'm doing it pretty simple I have no idea why its not working.  I had a applet with a single class and it worked fine.

This is kind of a filepath problem over a programming one I think

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, this

```
<applet code="Main" archive="RomanFury.jar" width="1280" height="720">
```

should be

```
<applet code="Build9.Main" archive="RomanFury.jar" width="1280" height="720">
```

because your game has many classes that are in a package called Build9 (and your .class files are in a folder called "Build9" in RomanFury.jar).

Comment: I get a NullPointerException for some reason.  When I go to the details it talks about the jar, but ooesnt actually say anything about the error/

Comment: Yes, well you haven't posted any code here. But a NullPointerException would seem to imply the applet is now starting.

Comment: I used `<applet code="Build9.Main" archive="media/RomanFury.jar" width="1280" height="720">` since the jar was not in the root.  Without media/ just gave me a class not found error.

There shouldn't be anything null in the jar, in NetBeans the applet runs successfully (has the window that states it).

What code would you like me to post?

Comment: @PatrickDuncan Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/).